# Google keeps rejecting incoming emails sent to Gmail with custom domain

Tags: gmail

Trying to set up Gmail so I can send and receive using my own domain.  In Gmail I have successfully added my email address in the "Send As" part.  Then I set up the MX records on my DNS to point to Google then waited for DNS to propagate.  I can send from Gmail as my own email address but Google rejects all incoming mail to the same address. I can tell from the message header it's Google rejecting and not my ISP.

Have I missed a step?

I've been trying for days and have followed various online instructions. Many of which reference controls that don't exist within Google Apps anymore.

Comment: Are you using Google Apps for Business? Without that, you can't use Google as your mail server. You could forward all mail to your Gmail address and use Gmail's "Send As" feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can only send email from a custom domain in GMail if you have an existing account at that address, or through Google Apps for Business (the free version of which has been canceled).

You can try using a service that offers free support for custom domains such as Outlook.com, and if you want to keep GMail just set up Outlook to forward everything to GMail, and then you can use Send As in GMail to send email from your custom domain.